# Printing a double-sided A5 document on A4 paper

Tags: double-sided, printing, pdfpages

I have a doubled-sided A5 landscape document with the following page order:

[image: page order: page 1 front, page 1 back, page 2 front, page 2 back, page 3 front, page 3 back, ...]

As my printer supports only A4 paper, I want to print two of these pages on one portrait A4 paper so that I can cut it in half to get sheets of the original size. In other words, what I need is the following page layout:

[image: desired result]

<sub>(The line separating the two pages is for demonstration purposes only, it is not part of the final result.)</sub>

**How can I achieve this layout with [`pdfpages`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)?**

---

The "naive" approach

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2]{a5-document}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: naive approach]

so the front and back side of each page are one the *same* side of the paper, instead of appearing on opposite faces.

---

At the moment, I'm using the following manual solution, which is quite tedious and error-prone, especially for large documents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages={1,3,2,4,5,7,6,8,...},nup=1x2]{a5-document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need a latex-solution? I think the using of `pdftk` in combination with a small script is also possible.

Comment: Isn't `\includepdf[pages=-,signature=4,landscape]{doc}` what you're looking for?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel A `pdftk` solution would also be acceptable.

Comment: @egreg With `\includepdf[pages=-,signature=4,landscape]{doc}`, the pages are placed at the correct position. They are, however, shrunk and rotated by 90 degrees (see [the attached image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1sHSt.png)).

Comment: @diabonas: try with `\includepdf[pages=-,signature=4]{doc}`. I guess it'll work. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda [Like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nWBDN.png), the landscape format is correct, but the front sides are rotated by 180 degrees. This has the effect that you have to flip the A5 paper around the horizontal instead of the vertical axis.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478506

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a way how to do this in ConTeXt:

```
\setuppagenumbering [location=]

\setuppapersize [A5, landscape] [A4]
\setuparranging [2TOPSIDE]

\starttext
    \dorecurse{8}{%
        \centerline{\definedfont[Serif at 256pt]\recurselevel}\page}
\stoptext
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

The `\setuppapersize` command states, that you want to write an A5 landscape document that should be printed on an A4 paper. `\setuparranging` is used to arrange the pages in the way you wish. Many more schemes are possible.

Comment: Pretty cool `:-)` Is there some way to include my existing document (which is written in LaTeX, but not in ConTeXt) with something like `pdfpages`, or do I have to rewrite it using ConTeXt?

Comment: You can use `\insertpages` or e.g. `\externalfigure`. See [include pages from PDF document](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Including_pages_from_PDF_document)

Comment: Great! I used `\insertpages[a5-document.pdf]` and I added `\setuplayout[backspace=0pt,topspace=0pt,width=middle,height=middle,location=middle,header=0pt,footer=0pt]` as described on [Imposition](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition) to make the included pages full width. Thank you very much! (I'll wait some time before I accept your answer.)

Comment: BTW: Your code is missing a `}`.

Comment: @diabonas It's these dwarfs again! They wander around random poeples' computer and eat innocent braces. Not they also discovered TeX.SE :(

Answer (score 8):

I was curious about an answer to this question, so a lot of search presented me with this great solution provided by Andreas Matthias, the author of `pdfpages`, posted in [comp.text.tex](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/1a26091bbb3cc9d4?pli=1). Since it has an interesting background, I'll provide the whole text, as it's fantastic.

<sup>Marked as community-wiki for obvious reasons. `:)`</sup>

Text from Andreas:

---

`pdfpages` imposes the pages such that they should be turned over the long edge (while printing), whereas with `psnup` they should be turned over the short edge. In Postscript this is called `/Tumble` which can be set to true or false.

Today all duplex printer should be able to do printing in short edge mode as well as long edge mode. So this shouldn't be a big issue.

However, if you like short edge printing more you can direct `pdftex` (`xetex`) to rotate every second page. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ifpdf,ifxetex}
\makeatletter
\ifpdf
  \EveryShipout{\ifodd\c@page\else\pdfpageattr{/Rotate 180}\fi}%
\fi
\ifxetex
  \EveryShipout{\ifodd\c@page\special{pdf: put @thispage << /Rotate 180 >>}%
\fi
}

\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-, nup=1x2, booklet=true, landscape]{a5.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[...]

Ciao

Andreas

---

<sup>**Note:** `\EveryShipout` is provided by the `everyshi` package. `:)`</sup>

Thanks to Andreas and this awesome code, I think the following code will help you:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ifpdf,ifxetex,everyshi}
\makeatletter
\ifpdf
  \EveryShipout{\ifodd\c@page\else\pdfpageattr{/Rotate 180}\fi}%
\fi
\ifxetex
  \EveryShipout{\ifodd\c@page\special{pdf: put @thispage << /Rotate 180 >>}%
\fi
}

\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,signature=4,angle=180]{a5-document}
\end{document}
```

*Now* I'm sure I know nothing about the ways of the TeX force. `:)`

Comment: The trick how to rotate pages is really great! The problem in this context, however, is that the page is rotated as a whole. This leads to a wrong placement of the pages, e.g. page 1 front on page 2 front instead of page 1 front on page 1 back ([see the example output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h5No6.png)). To fix this, one would have to rotate the single A5 pages instead. I think this could be done by selectively rotating the pages of the original `a5-document.pdf`, but I think I'll go with [Marco's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36565/3323) as it is more straightforward `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

For newbies like me:

- create your pdf that needs to be in A5 format. (i named it "book.pdf")
- create a tex empty project (i named it "bookA5print.tex")
- paste/write this in your new .tex file:

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper,final]{article}

  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \usepackage{ifpdf,ifxetex,everyshi}
  \makeatletter

  \ifpdf
  \EveryShipout{\ifodd\c@page\else\pdfpageattr{/Rotate 180}\fi}%
  \fi

  \ifxetex
  \EveryShipout{\ifodd\c@page\special{pdf: put @thispage << /Rotate 180 >>}%
  \fi
  }

  \fi
  \makeatother

  \begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=-, nup=1x2, booklet=true, landscape]{book.pdf}
  \end{document}
  ```

then execute on your terminal `xelatex bookA5print.tex`

this avoids the rotation problem.

thanks to Paolo Cereda and Andreas

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `4 on 2, odd then even` layout of [`pgfmorepages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfmorepages).  This puts two logical pages on one physical page, but uses the order 1,3,2,4 (repeated).  When printed double sided, this would put the 1st and 2nd pages back to back and the 3rd and 4th, and so on.