# Booklets on legalpaper using pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages

I want to make a signature for a small pocket booklet. I don't want to use ISO sized paper, but every reference to `pdfpages` uses A5 or A6 booklet examples. Is this possible to do? Do I need to produce a distinct PDF file for each page of the booklet? Should I be using a different package or `documentclass` to accomplish this, or should I be investing time in `pdfpages`? I'm a little overwhelmed by the documentation, and unsure about how to proceed.

I used the example from this website:

http://www.mostlymaths.net/2010/11/creating-a6-booklets-in-7-easy-steps.html

File 1 (`thedocument.pdf`):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \begin{document}
      \lipsum[1-40]
   \end{document}
```

File 2 (`b2x1.pdf`):

```
\documentclass[legalpaper]{article}
   \usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx,epsfig}
   \usepackage[left=2cm,top=2.cm,bottom=2.cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
   \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
   \begin{document}
      \includepdf[pages=-, signature=80,landscape, frame=true]{thedocument.pdf}
   \end{document}
```

File 3 (`b4x1.pdf`):

```
\documentclass[legalpaper]{article}
   \usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx,epsfig}
   \usepackage[left=2cm,top=2.cm,bottom=2.cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
   \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
   \begin{document}
      \includepdf[pages=-, signature=40,landscape, frame=true]{b2x1.pdf}
   \end{document}
```

File 4 (`b8x1.pdf`):

```
\documentclass[legalpaper]{article}
   \usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx,epsfig}
   \usepackage[left=2cm,top=2.cm,bottom=2.cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
   \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
   \begin{document}
      \includepdf[pages=-, signature=20,landscape, frame=true]{b4x1.pdf}
   \end{document}
```

I get a strange output. There's a very large margin on the left and right of the page, and there's only one page of the document showing up on each paper (instead of multiple `pdfpages` per paper).

Example:
[image: Example]

Comment: As always, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful. Perhaps you could show us the solution you'd like to use with ISO, and what problems you are running into when you try to adapt it to non-ISO. It is not obvious to me why that should be different?

Comment: @cfr I'm sorry about that. I updated the post.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the size using `geometry`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[paperheight=7.5in,paperwidth=5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[pages=1-8, signature=8,landscape]{pgfmanual}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Change the paper size suitably (as you wish) in

```
\usepackage[paperheight=7.5in,paperwidth=5in]{geometry}
```

## Edit:

In the `thedocument.tex` you have to choose the paper width to be (at most) half of the `legal paper`s height, i.e. 279.4mm. In this I have set the width to be `170mm`

```
\begin{filecontents}{thedocument.tex}
\documentclass[twoside]{article}   %% changed
\usepackage[paperheight=215.9mm,paperwidth=170mm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,inner=2cm,outer=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-65]
\end{document}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[legalpaper]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\immediate\write18{pdflatex thedocument}
\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages=-, signature=12,  landscape,frame=true]{thedocument.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm going to give this a try. A quick question: does the paper height/width setting for `geometry` set the size for the individual `pdfpages` on a single page, or for the entire piece of paper that the `pdfpages` are on?

Comment: Using `geometry` like this didn't work. It only changed the size of the physical page I'm printing on. It didn't make any difference if I kept the original `geometry` setting on the final b8x1 page.

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley `pdfpages` will automatically scale the contents to the paper size, so theoretically if you choose preoper physical paper size this should work.

Comment: perhaps I'm doing something wrong? It's not working, regardless of whether I use the `geometry` setting in the `pdfpages` TeX file, or the `thedocument` TeX file. To make things easier, I've used only one `pdfpages` TeX file, and eliminated b4x1 and b8x1. Either way, I'm getting the same result.

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley Remove `left=2cm,top=2.cm,bottom=2.cm,right=2cm`, you won't need it in `b2x1` document. Put it in `thedocument` instead. Also the final pagenumber and the signatures should be same as in `pages=1-40,signature=40,`.

Comment: just did that, still having no luck. I tried changing around `nup` also, which sets the number of logical pages per sheet of paper, and nothing. There's definitely something strange going on. This is the code I currently have, maybe you'll find some error with it? http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kFXzfiAb

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley Now I gotta go. I will see later on today.

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Solved here: [How to automatically output page order to print 8 pages of a booklet on a single sheet of Letter paper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179119/how-to-automatically-output-page-order-to-print-8-pages-of-a-booklet-on-a-single)