# Producing crop marks fit for octavo signature layout

Tags: crop, signatures, octavo, cropmarks

Normally I use the `crop` package within a `book` class to produce individual sheets with crop marks. Now I would like to produce sheets for octavo signature binding, that is, eight pages on each side of the large sheet where the inside margins between even and odd pages do not crop because they fold. I know how to put the "mosaic" together from the PDF produced by `pdflatex`, but before I do that I need to add the crop marks and position the text area on the pages properly. I seem unable to achieve that with the `crop` package.

I can remove the inside crop marks with:

`\usepackage[cam,a4,center,mount2]{crop}`

[image: Outer crop marks, centered]

But I seem unable to shift the page area to make it flush with the inner border. What I want to get is this:

[image: Outer crop parks, flush to inside]

Of curse I know that the `centered` option should not be part of the final solution, but if I remove it the text area flushes to top left on all pages, so I left it in here for the purpose of illustration.

Also, I know I could technically have the crop marks only on every 16th page, and that would be fine if it were the case.

I am looking primarily for a TeX solution (configuring or replacing the `crop` package) but a command-line tool to assemble the signatures and add crop marks would be a perfectly acceptable alternative.

Comment: Would `pdfpages` package be an option? It would possibly allow you to get directly the big sheet pdf. See package doc.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179119/how-to-automatically-output-page-order-to-print-8-pages-of-a-booklet-on-a-single

Comment: It seems to me that both (`pdfpages` and the question referenced above) address the latter part of my problem, where I'm not completely clueless, i.e., the (re)arrangement of the pages. But it does not deal with the crop marks, which are the main problem for me.

Comment: Provide the `MWE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, combining includepdf and crop seems to work:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[cam,width=25cm,height=35cm,center]{crop}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-,noautoscale,landscape,signature=8]{mydocument.pdf} % Document is A5 format

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution if you could switch to `memoir` class:

```
\documentclass[showtrims]{memoir}
\quarkmarks
\setstocksize{20cm}{16cm}
\setpagemr{16cm}{12cm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{30mm}{15mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{40mm}{20mm}{*}
\setheadfoot{5mm}{5mm}
\checkandfixthelayout

\makeatletter

\let\mytmarktl\tmarktl
\renewcommand{\tmarktl}{\ifodd\c@page\mytmarktl\else\relax\fi} 

\let\mytmarkbl\tmarkbl
\renewcommand{\tmarkbl}{\ifodd\c@page\mytmarkbl\else\relax\fi}

\let\mytmarktr\tmarktr 
\renewcommand{\tmarktr}{\ifodd\c@page\else\mytmarktr\fi}

\let\mytmarkbr\tmarkbr 
\renewcommand{\tmarkbr}{\ifodd\c@page\else\mytmarkbr\fi}

\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```